# Passing data between components in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to do a fake comment component in vue.js. I'm passing the comments throught an $emit, but i can't pass the name from the person who wrote it too, what should i do?
I'm using "Comment Grid" to loop throught the comments, "comment" to hold the comment model and "newcomment" as the method to create a new one.

````
    **app.vue**
    <template>
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 mx-auto">
          <app-new-comment  @commentAdded="newComment"></app-new-comment>
          <app-comment-grid  :comments="comments"> </app-comment-grid>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
  Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
  import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
  import CommentGrid from './components/CommentGrid.vue';
  import NewComment from './components/NewComment.vue';

  export default {
      data: function() {
        return {
          comments: [
            'Comentário vazio',
          ],
          maxComments: 999
        }
      },
     methods: {
        newComment(comment) {
            this.comments.push(comment);
        },
      },
      components: {
        appCommentGrid: CommentGrid,
        appNewComment: NewComment,
      }
  }





**comment grid**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <app-comment v-for="comment in comments">{{ comment }}</app-comment>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Comment from './Comment.vue'
import New from './NewComment'

export default {
  props: ['comments'],

  components: {
    appComment: Comment,
    appNew: New
  }

}
</script>
```


**comment** 

```
<template>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="photo">
        <img src="../assets/pf.png" alt="Picture" />
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <div class="name">
          <div class="name">{{ }} - yesterday at 19h35</div>
        </div>
        <slot></slot>
        <!-- <a href="/" class="url_checkout">Answer</a> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Comment from './NewComment.vue'

export default {
}
</script>
```

**newComment**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form">
        <p></p>
        <input :myName="name" type="text" placeholder="Nome" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email *" />
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" v-model="comment" placeholder="Write a comment"></textarea>
        <button @click.prevent="createNew">Add comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Comment from './Comment'

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      comment: ''

    }
  },
  methods: {
    createNew () {
      this.$emit('commentAdded', this.comment)

      console.log(this.name)
      this.comment = ''

    }
  }

}
</script>
```
````

Comment: suggestion - remove the style from the code you posted ... it's irrelevant and makes the code longer than it needs to be to help you

Comment: Style removed, thanks.

Comment: We need a bit more information: Why can't you send the user data aswell? Where is it stored? I don't see any usage of your `new comment` component. Where do you catch the `commentAdded` event?

Comment: It's everything there, the data ins't stored anywhere yet cause i can't even make it work.